# Is it enough to show a sequence converge to infinity if the limit of this sequence is greater or equal infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose I derive $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=\infty$. Can I conclude $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can conclude that.

We normally don't say that the sequence converges to infinity.

We say that the sequence diverges to infinity